# Perdida del validationsummary al hacer RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validación

Buen dia.

mi duda es la siguiente, lo que pasa es que tengo un modelo como este:

```
  public class RegistroUsuarioDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio!!!")]
    [Display(Name ="No. Documento")]
    public int Num_Documento { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio!!!")]
    public string Nombres { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio!!!")]
    [Display(Name ="Correo Personal")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo no puede estar vacio!!!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name ="Contraseña")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Este campo no puede estar vacio!!!")]
    [Display(Name ="Confirmar Contraseña")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPass { get; set; }

    public string Cargo { get; set; }

    public string Salario { get; set; }

}
```

y en mi controlador de la accion Index esto:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var comboContratos = new List<ComboTiposContratos>();
        var comboAreas = new List<Areas>();
        var comboDocumentos = new List<Tipos_documento>();
        comboContratos = rudao.CargaComboContratos();
        comboAreas = rudao.CargaComboAreas();
        comboDocumentos = rudao.CargaComboDocumentos();
        var liscontratos = new SelectList(comboContratos, "Id", "Descripcion");
        var lisareas = new SelectList(comboAreas, "Id", "descripcion");
        var lisdocu = new SelectList(comboDocumentos, "Id", "Descripcion");
        ViewData["combocontratos"] = liscontratos;
        ViewData["comboareas"] = lisareas;
        ViewData["combodocu"] = lisdocu;
        return View();
    }
```

tengo otra acción con el [httppost] que recibe mis datos desde el formulario la cuestion es que cuando mi modelo no es valido no me muestra los mensajes ya que tengo que hacer un redirecaction algo asi tengo:

```
    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Registro(RegistroUsuarioDto rudto,  string  FechaIngreso, string FechaFin, int combocontratos = 0, int comboareas = 0, int combodocu = 0)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

         int resultado = rudao.InsertUsuario(rudto, combocontratos, comboareas, FechaIngreso, FechaFin,combodocu);
            if(resultado == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ViewsuccesUsuario", "HojaVidaDto");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "No se ha registrado el usuario revisar!!!");
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "No se ha registrado el usuario revisar!!!");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

La cuestión es que no puedo hacer un return view ya que mis SelectList quedarian vacíos y me generara un error. Entonces como debo hacer para mantener los mensajes de mi validationSummary en la vista? y en general como debe uno manejar estos casos para no perder información?

Answer (score 1):

Veamos, hay un par de cosas que cambiar para que pueda funcionar el ModelState.

> 1. Debes enviarle el modelo a la vista cuando este es inválido, para que el formulario pueda mostrar los valores que el usuario había
>      ingresado.
> 2. En el caso de tu vista que requiere de combos, deberás volver a realizar la carga de los datos por lo que te sugiero refactorizarlo en
>      un método.
> 3. Sería recomendable que refactorizes tu modelo e incluyas la FechaIngreso, comboareas, etc. en RegistroUsuarioDto para tener un
>      modelo más cohesivo y poder facilitar el mostrar los valores
>      previamente seleccionados al usuario cuando este no pasa el proceso de
>      validación.

```
   [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Registro(RegistroUsuarioDto rudto)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            int resultado = rudao.InsertUsuario(rudto,rudto.combocontratos,rudto.comboareas,rudto.FechaIngreso,rudto.FechaFin,rudto.combodocu);
            //int resultado = rudao.InsertUsuario(rudto);
            if(resultado == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ViewsuccesUsuario", "HojaVidaDto");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "No se ha registrado el usuario revisar!!!");
                PrecargarCombos();
                return View("Index",rudto);
            }
        }
        else
        {           
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "No se ha registrado el usuario revisar!!!");
            PrecargarCombos();
            return View("Index",rudto);
        }
    }

    private void PrecargarCombos(){
         var comboContratos = new List<ComboTiposContratos>();
         var comboAreas = new List<Areas>();
         var comboDocumentos = new List<Tipos_documento>();
        comboContratos = rudao.CargaComboContratos();
        comboAreas = rudao.CargaComboAreas();
        comboDocumentos = rudao.CargaComboDocumentos();
        var liscontratos = new SelectList(comboContratos, "Id", "Descripcion");
        var lisareas = new SelectList(comboAreas, "Id", "descripcion");
        var lisdocu = new SelectList(comboDocumentos, "Id", "Descripcion");
        ViewData["combocontratos"] = liscontratos;
        ViewData["comboareas"] = lisareas;
        ViewData["combodocu"] = lisdocu;
    }
```

Comment: he hecho eso lo que me recomiendas y tienes la razon lo intente pero no se muy bien como llenar los combos ya que los datos tengo que cargarlos de una base de datos tienes alguna idea de como podria hacerlo creando eso como tu me dices dentro del mismo modelo?